# c# Using LiNQ to remove multiple rows in Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

This should be simple but i am not able to figure this out. I have a Datatable that has Name, Age where there are rows that have student names, but then multiple rows of special students' Name 'Chris's, and John's. the end result should have a table with all the rows except Chris and John to be combined into one row called Other with the sum of their age.

ie.

```
NAME | AGE
Tom | 20
John | 15
Peter | 5
John | 2
Tom | 33
Chris | 20
```

End Result:

```
NAME | AGE
Tom | 20
Peter | 5
Tom | 33
Other | 37
```

This is what im doing right now:

```
var others = table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["NAME"].ToString().Equals("Chris") || x["NAME"].ToString().Equals("John"));
var tmpOthers = 0;
foreach (DataRow otherRow in others)
            tmpOthers += decimal.Parse(otherRow["AGE"].ToString());
table = table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !x["NAME"].ToString().Equals("Chris") || !x["NAME"].ToString().Equals("John")).CopyToDataTable();
table.Add(//OTHER-ROW-Here)
```

This works but i know there must be an easier way to do this in a single LiNQ statement. also i could not put the table.Rows.Remove in the same for loop because of iteration change.

Comment: RemoveRange? https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Does a `name` always starts with upper case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do that using Linq + delegate. Why? A solution with delegate is more elegant and more specific for such of case, because a name may starts with big or small letter. Check below solution:

```
//delegate to return "Other" for {"Chris","John"} - ignoring case
Func<string, string> GetOtherName = delegate(string s)
    {
        if(string.Equals(s, "Chris", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                string.Equals(s, "John", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return "Other";
        else
            return s;
    };

//get total age for "Other"
var otherAge = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x=>GetOtherName(x.Field<string>("NAME")) == "Other")
            .Select(x=>x.Field<int>("AGE")).Sum();

//remove "Other" rows
dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x=>GetOtherName(x.Field<string>("NAME")) == "Other")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r=>r.Delete());

//finally add "other" row
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{"Other", otherAge});
```

Result:

```
NAME  AGE
Tom   20 
Peter 5 
Tom   33 
Other 37
```

For further details, please see: [Func Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Super! This is so much cleaner! Love the coding style

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use a `for` loop for that purpose like

```
for(int i=0; i<others.Count(); i++)
    table.Rows.Remove(others[i]);
```

Comment: It works with a for loop but the code i gave is a little messy and i know there should be a way to write all of that logic into one single LiNQ statement. Something like `table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["NAME"].ToString().Equals("Chris") || x["NAME"].ToString().Equals("John")).(sum up the AGE in some local variable).Removes these rows.CopyToTable()` a logic like that

Comment: @ civic.sir In my opinion that giant linq statement is messier than your original code.  You could do a .ForEach() on the .Where() result set, but I'm not sure how to RemoveRange on that Where() again after that.

Comment: @dckuehn Yes that is what im looking for .. .ForEach().Where and then I can simply do a copytoDataTable() at the end no?

Comment: @civic.sir I don't think you can have a single LINQ statement that both adds a new entry to the list, **and** removes entities at the same time.  Even if you can, I think that would be *messier* than your current solution.

Comment: Ahh i see. kk makes sense Thanks a lot

Comment: @civic.sir, not sure why you feel that LINQ solution would be any better than what you have. AFAIK, that's won't benefit on performance ground.